# Get height from html and insert into state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to make a list of comments. I get html from the backend.
When the height of the comment block is high, I need to trim the block using the max-height property.
[image]
The problem is that I cannot get this height from the backend, I get it from the html that I insert, that is, after the render.
It turns out I need to make two renders, the first happens after receiving comments so that the height can be calculated, the second happens when I take the height and insert it into the state with comments.

When I insert a state with a height into the comment list, an error occurs:

**Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.**

How can i solve this problem?

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {CommentsList} from "./CommentsList";


const comments = [
  {
    id: '1',
    author: 'Han Solo',
    avatar: 'https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png',
    content: '<p>Ddwe23f423<strong><em>fw</em></strong></p>',
    date: 1607350845385,
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    author: 'Han11',
    avatar: 'https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png',
    content:
      '<p>asdasad adfs dh d hadg</p><p>asdasad adfs dh d hadg</p><p>asdasad adfs dh d hadg</p><p>asdasad adfs dh d hadg</p><p>asdasad adfs dh d hadg</p><p>asdasad adfs dh d hadg</p><p>asdasad adfs dh d hadg</p><p>asdasad adfs dh d hadg</p><p>asdasad adfs dh d hadg</p><p>asdasad adfs dh d hadg</p><p>asdasad adfs dh d hadg</p><p>asdasad adfs dh d hadg</p><p>asdasad adfs dh d hadg</p><p>asdasad adfs dh d hadg</p><p>asdasad adfs dh d hadg</p><p>asdasad adfs dh d hadg</p>',
    date: 1607342028321,
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    author: 'Han Solo',
    avatar: 'https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png',
    content: '<p>Ddwe23f42dddddddddd3<strong><em>fw</em></strong></p>',
    date: 1607342028321,
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    author: 'Han Solo',
    avatar: 'https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png',
    content: '<p>asdasad adfs dh d hadg</p>',
    date: 1607342028321,
  },
]

const App = () => {

  return (
    <div>
      <CommentsList comments={comments} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

CommentsList.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

export function CommentsList({comments}) {

  const [commentsList, commentsListSet] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    commentsListSet(comments)
  }, [comments])

  const heightCheck = (height, id) => { // here second render I want insert height
    commentsListSet(commentsList.map((comment) => { // Error here
      if (comment.id === id) {
        comment.height = height; // I need this height in commentsList for button "more"
      }
      return comment
    }))
  }

  return <ul>
    {commentsList.map(e => { // here first render
      return <li key={e.id}>
        <div
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: e.content}}
          ref={(html) => html && heightCheck(html.clientHeight, e.id)} // Here i get height from ref
        />
      </li>
    })}
  </ul>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is because your are calling state setter in return statement which results in re-rendering of component, which again calls the setter and again your component re-render and this sets the loop. Instead you can initialize a flag which holds render status and set when your component get mounted as I have done in the below code.

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {CommentsList} from './CommentList';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CommentsList comments={[{id:1, content:'React is all about UI'}, {id:2, content:'UseEffect can be used as componentDidUpdate or componentDidMount'}]} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**CommentsList.js**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, useRef} from 'react';

export function CommentsList({comments}) {

  const [commentsList, commentsListSet] = useState(comments)
    const [htmlRendered, setHtmlRendered] = useState(false)
    const commentItemsRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Work as componentDidMount
        setHtmlRendered(true);
  }, [])

    const commentHeight = htmlRendered?commentItemsRef.current.clientHeight:0;
    return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>Height: {commentHeight}</div>
        <div ref={commentItemsRef}>
            <ul>
                {
                    commentsList.map((comment) => <li key={comment.id}>{comment.content}</li>)
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>);
}
```

Hope this will helps. Let me know if you face any issue in running code.

[Updated code]
Here I have calculated height of each list item as you have done.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

export function CommentsList({ comments }) {
  const [commentsList, commentsListSet] = useState(comments);
  const [htmlRendered, setHtmlRendered] = useState(false);
  const commentItemsRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Work as componentDidMount
    setHtmlRendered(true);
  }, []);

  const commentHeight = htmlRendered ? commentItemsRef.current.clientHeight : 0;
  const renderedComments = [];
  if (htmlRendered) {
    const commentListItems = Array.from(
      commentItemsRef.current.querySelectorAll("li")
    );
    commentListItems.forEach((item) => {
      const commentid = item.getAttribute("commentid");
      const content = item.innerHTML;
      renderedComments.push({
        id: commentid,
        content: content,
        height: item.clientHeight
      });
    });

    // Final Rendered Comment that can be used
    console.log(renderedComments);
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>Height: {commentHeight}</div>
      <div ref={commentItemsRef}>
        <ul>
          {commentsList.map((comment) => (
            <li key={comment.id} commentid={comment.id}>
              {comment.content}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: in your example you are calculating the height of one block, i need to calculate in a loop, better try to change my example so that there is no confusion

Comment: I have updated my code according to what you were trying to achieve. Only thing I want to illustrate from my code is that you cannot set the state inside return statement. You can only set the state in event handlers or useEffect hook inside function components. I have provided way around to achieve this.

Comment: and still i cant get the height in the block li

Answer (score 0):

I do not use react but is setting your line-height a possibility? You can check approx. the number of lines and calculate it at the point of retrieval and trim accordingly?

Comment: no, I can’t count the number of lines because at different screen resolutions there will be a different number of lines

Comment: You should be able to set font-size and line-height... Alternatively you can use a div and set the overflow hidden.

Comment: I don't understand how to use font-size and line-height here. How can i use div if i don't know where it is needed and where not? because I get the height after I insert the data into the html

Comment: I do not know react, I hope someone else can help you out. I had assumed that you know the height of the div i.e. so it is fixed and the overflow would have been hidden. Another idea that comes to mind is to use mutation observer and check the height attribute but I will stop there as I might be polluting the reply section.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is not the best way. It is best to do this with css. Because once you add these contents to the dom, you do not need to remove them.

But to solve it with javascript, you need to present.

```
const [commentsList, commentsListSet] = useState(comments);

React.useEffect(() => {
  const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
  wrapper.style.position = 'absolute';
  wrapper.style.top = '-99999px';
  wrapper.style.left = '-99999px';

  const domItems = commentsList.map((item) => {
    const domItem = document.createElement('div');
    domItem.innerHTML = item.content;
    return { item, domItem };
  });

 domItems.forEach((element) => {
   wrapper.appendChild(element.domItem);
 });

document.body.appendChild(wrapper);

commentsListSet(
  domItems.map(({ item, domItem }) => ({
  ...item,
  height: domItem.clientHeight,
 }))
);

 wrapper.remove();
 }, [commentsList]);
```